# Group of Google Data Studio reports same template for multiple customers with a parameter

Tags: looker-studio

I want to give each customer a separate copy of the same Google Data Studio report, each copy with a hard coded parameter value (the customer id) so that all their charts are filtered to show only that customers data.  But then I can update the template and all customers will immediately get a new version of the report, but still each customer with their own data.  Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can [Filter by email address](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766?hl=en) in your report and use a single report for all users. OR
2. You can do this by creating a Community Connector, enabling user based view in the connector, and using that connector in a report with viewer's credentials enforced. This will let viewers see only their own data when they view the dashboard and also allow up to update that single dashboard whenever you want. For step by step instructions see [this official guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/row-level-filtering).

Comment: Thanks!  I think another approach is a URL parameter.  I can use a secure key which i then join to the actual customer id.  But I have another problem, I want to use the same URL parameter to control multiple reports but Google Data Studio doesn't allow different params to have the same Name.  Any ideas please?  I will open a separate issue for that too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67300644/google-data-studio-can-one-url-param-control-multiple-bigquery-data-sources

Comment: The problems with URL parameter are: 1) You have to give separate URLs to each customer and maintain the list. 2) It is easy to leak one customer's data to another by human mistake. 3) its easy for a key to become compromised. Anyone who has the link can see your customer's data. In which case you have change the key, update your mapping, and send the customer a new URL. I would advice against using this approach.

Comment: Yes fair points.  The challenge with email is that some customers do not have a Gmail-compabible email to login with.

Comment: @Mark how do you implement the URL parameter solution? I'm currently facing the same challenge, but I do not need to keep the same URL. I just need to change the report according to the client viewing in my webapp (the report in embedded). Thank you in advance

Comment: @quefro If users are logged into your web app, you can try this approach which is more secure: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials

Comment: Thanks everyone. For now I got it working by creating a unique random token per customer and passing it in as a URL parameter. Then inside the custom SQL queries I join on a key table and then filter on the customer id.  Works find but a bit awkward and has some security vulnerability. I need to try to understand what Minhaz referenced https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials

Comment: @quefro I created a BigQuery table mapping a secure randome customer key to the customer id.  Then I have all my datasources take the secure id from a URL parameter and join on that table to only show the customer's data.  You can also cycle the keys as needed.